# Does Material-UI support react-native

Tags: material-ui

Material-UI v0.18.7 [docs example](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs) has a build for ios/android, but it is not clear to me if it also works for react-native. While I could make it work for react (web), I could not make it work for react-native.

Is it possible to run the [docs example](https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/tree/master/docs) for react-native ?

PS: If it doesn't work for react-native, then why do the ios/android build exist ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`android` and `ios` was only folders for poc, and that implementation has `react-native 0.17` version only, react native changed a lot through the time and now has `^0.47 version`.
As I see, previous roadmap of working with react native included writing of native components and reorganisation of project,. So material-ui 0.18.7 does not support react-native,

As they wrote, there are a lot of troubles:

> Bringing the web API to the native
>
> We gonna have to make sacrifices, I'm expecting some web feature to be really hard to implement on native, for instance, the CSS media queries, the CSS animations. (advanced CSS rules)
>
> Handling missing native API in the web
>
> Some of the missing web API features is around touch handling, scroll & infinite list view, native components like a DatePicker or a Drawer.

So, it is only included in roadmap, check out discussion about it here:
https://github.com/callemall/material-ui/issues/593